# Какие есть библиотеки или способы для воспроизведения потокового видео (http) Android?

Tags: java, android, видео, потоки-данных

Есть задача, воспроизводить трансляции с сервера с ссылкой вида `http://8.8.8.8......`

Пытался:

1. Штатный проигрыватель (VideoView..), не может воспроизвести половину потоков.
2. [VitamioSDK](https://www.vitamio.org/en/), рассинхрон(где то полсекунды) видео со звуком + тормоза HD-качества на любом устройстве, хотя китайцы обещали 780 и 1080р.
3. ExoPlayer от Google , тоже не захотел воспроизводить.

Comment: А какой формат стрима ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: У вас свой стрим или совершенно сторонний? Если свой, то лучше на сервере подобрать кодек, пригодный для проигрывания на мобильных.  http:// - это бесполезная информация, нужен используемый в потоке кодек.

Answer (score 1):

Решилось сборкой VLClib для андроида.